# Regular Expression for extracting strings in quotes (under certain requirements)

Tags: regex

maybe the problems seems bathetic, but at the moment I have a real problem in extracting strings from quotes, but fulfilling certain criteria. These are

- Just the text in quotes should be extracted, but not the quotes itself 
  e.g. I live in "Germany"  -> Germany
- If there are no quotes the text should be returned completely
  e.g. I live in Germany -> I live in Germany
- If the quotes are protected by \ they should be treated as normal characters and be extracted, but without the backslash 
  e.g. I live in \"Germany\" -> I live in "Germany"
- If the last quotation is missing, the rest of the text should be returned
  e.g. I "live in Germany -> live in Germany

All my experiments failed. The best guess of mine was:

```
    (?<=(?<!\\)").*?(?=(?<!\\)")
```

The problem of it is that if there are no quotes at all, the extracted string is empty.

Thanks a lot for the help
  Best regards
  cerebro

Comment: Why is it necessary to cramp all this logic into a single regex? There are tools much more suited for this. Multiple regex backed by a programming language comes to mind, so does string operations.

Comment: What language are you using? Advanced tools could be of great help for such a complicated case.

Comment: I use LabView, and that's also the point to do it within one single regexp -> Performance reasons. The regexp method from them is based on PCRE, so fully compatible to most of described operations possible with regular expressions. Of course it is possible to substring all text, but copying strings when parsing XML requests and HTTP messages is not much performing.
This is also one requirement ;)

Comment: @user2273693 So the string you're testing on is `I live in "Germany"`, or is there other sentences in the string ?

Comment: A more practical example based on HTTP headers:<br>
header: xxxyyyzzz<br>
SOAPAction: "myRequest" <br/>
otherHeader: aaabbbccc<br/>

with substring I cut 'SOAPAction: "myRequest"' and now I want to extract 'myRequest'<br/>
The quotes are not mandatory!<br/>
Also 'SOAPAction: myRequest' is valid and nevertheless I want to extract 'myRequest'

Comment: Another example: I want to extract an EMPTY STRING i.e. "". Using my regular expression, I cannot decide whether the string was really "" or if it was any string, but without quotes.

Comment: Regex isn't a magic wand. If I were you, I would really try to use some built in functions.

Comment: Hmmm, what a pity...that's what I have at the moment. Checking if regexp returns an empty string or not. If empty then to check once more the original string, if it was explicitly "" otherwise simply return it. I thought maybe there was a more elegant solution. Upper solution of mine works perfectly for strings really containing quotes, but it totally fails if they are missing.

Answer (score 1):

For the test cases written in your question following regex should work for you:

```
^([^"\n\\]*)(?:\\(")|"|)([^"\n\\]*)(?:\\(")|"|)(.*)$
```

You need to concatenate group # 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to get your captured string.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/u6m08cRo1v

Comment: Not a bad solution, thanks a lot...but in the following case it produces problems, because you have to check the groups:
[link](http://www.rubular.com/r/BIC1Eid6qc)

Comment: I looked at your links and in all the cases this regex has worked fine. As I said you need to combine `group # 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` to get your final string.

Comment: Sorry, I did not comment it correctly. If you take match 2 and 4 in my example and combine groups # {1-5} you have again your original string (without space and quotes). That means before concatenating you have to check the groups `if(#1 && #3) print #3 else concat(#1..#5)`

Comment: As per your problem double quotes need to be removed if they appear with escaping. For case # 2 your final string should be: `hallo Holland` and for case # 4 it should be: `I live in Germany`. Hence you can see for all the cases you can just do `concat(#1..#5)`

Comment: For case #2 it should be `Holland`, and for case #4 it should be `live in Germany`. See definition in question above under bullet 1 and 4. However, thank you anyway. Starting from your approach I hopefully find an appropriate solution, it's already a very good suggestion

Comment: Ah sorry I misread the problem. I will be offline for few hours, see if this works out for you. Otherwise leave me a comment if you want me to improve upon this answer and I will try my best.